# Growing Goji Berry from dried seeds

Tags: seedlings, germination, goji

I am wanting to grow some Goji Berry bushes.

A few months ago I soaked some (regular dried store bought) Goji fruit, then cut them open, used the baggie method to germinate the individual seeds and transplanted them.

The plants started growing, but all of them (and there were more then a dozen) died after transplanting them - I suspect I transplanted them way to early, and also the environment was wrong.    I want to try again now that Spring is on its way - but want to avoid the mistakes I made.

[ At the moment New Zealand is going into Spring its still quite cold - most days are 10-15 degrees C outside, but a lot of sun, and nights between 3 and 15 c.    I can keep them indoors in an artificial environment, but I suspect my growing light is not great for them.  I also have a polytunnel - this seems to be nice and warm during the day, but cut out a lot of light and probably only marginally warmer then outside at night ]

Questions:

1. Should I remove the Goji seeds from the Goji Berry when trying to germinate them or am I better just planting the whole Goji Berry fruit in the ground ?
2. Does the temperature of the ground need to be consistently over 22 degrees for germination to occur ?
3. Once germination has occurred how do I get the seedlings to a point where I can plant them in the ground outside without them dying ?

Comment: You might have more success transplanting them if you either start them in such as an unheated greenhouse, or give them potassium and/or a humidity dome with the transplant (no nitrogen at this time). Keep them out of strong sun for a while after the transplant. Anyway, did you harden them off before transplanting? How?

Comment: Germination in an unheated greenhouse in the early spring may take longer, but the plants are more used to outdoor conditions, including temperatures, and they germinate when they're ready. They need ventilation, though. I haven't started Goji this way, but I have several related members of the Solanaceae family (tomatoes, multiple species of peppers, Morelle De Balbis, eggplant, several species of ground cherry, true potato seed, and tomatillos), and they've all been strong and transplanted well.